# node: removing duplicate objects from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array of objects and I would like to remove duplicate items. The following discusses the topic however the ES6 solutions do not appear to work with objects:
[Unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

```
var myArray=[{fname:"Bob", sname:"Brown"},{fname:"Jill",sname:"White"},{fname:"Bob", sname:"Brown"}];
var unique = myArray.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
/*
[ { fname: 'Bob', sname: 'Brown' },
  { fname: 'Jill', sname: 'White' },
  { fname: 'Bob', sname: 'Brown' } ]
*/
let unique = [...new Set(myArray)];
/*
[ { fname: 'Bob', sname: 'Brown' },
  { fname: 'Jill', sname: 'White' },
  { fname: 'Bob', sname: 'Brown' } ]
*/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use _.uniqBy or _.uniqWith from lodash ;)

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

const myArray=[{fname:"Bob", sname:"Brown"},{fname:"Jill",sname:"White"},{fname:"Bob", sname:"Brown"}];

console.log(_.uniqWith(myArray, _.isEqual));
```

Comment: Code works thank you. Having trouble understanding the difference between uniq.js, uniqBy.js & uniqWith.js

Answer (score 2):

With lodash you can use `_.uniqBy` or `_.uniqWith` - see the answer by Steven Leclerc.

See: https://lodash.com/ for details.

If you're serious about writing code then you shouldn't reinvent the wheel for simple cases like this.

If you want to know how to implement it properly, see the source code here:

- https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/uniq.js
- https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/uniqBy.js
- https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/uniqWith.js
- https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/sortedUniq.js
- https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/sortedUniqBy.js
- https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/.internal/baseUniq.js
- https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/.internal/baseSortedUniq.js

Keep in mind that when you use JSON.stringify then first of all you must put it inside of a try/catch block because your program will crash for some data (or you should use [tryjson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tryjson) - disclaimer, I'm the author of that module) and that you will get false positives of objects that are different but have the same JSON serialization.

Comment: @StevenLeclerc thanks. I updated my answer and also referred to yours.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to use the same solution you referred to after a small modification; as using Objects as keys is not possible, we can use them as JSON which is string:

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function() {
    var u = {}, a = [];
    for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i) {
        var index = JSON.stringify(this[i]);
        if(u.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
            continue;
        }
        a.push(this[i]);
        u[index] = 1;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Without lodash:

```
function removeDuplicates(myArr, prop) {
  return myArr.filter((element, pos, arr) => {
    return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(element[prop]) === pos;
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here first and last element does not represent same object, therefore it is not removed from set

```
var myArray=[{fname:"Bob", sname:"Brown"},{fname:"Jill",sname:"White"},{fname:"Bob", sname:"Brown"}];
var set1 = new Set(myArray);
console.log([...set1]);
/*
[ { fname: 'Bob', sname: 'Brown' },
  { fname: 'Jill', sname: 'White' },
  { fname: 'Bob', sname: 'Brown' } ]
*/
```

Here only one object is added to set, as both are same.

```
var set2 = new Set();
var obj1 = {fname:"Bob", sname:"Brown"};
set2.add(obj1);
set2.add(obj1);
console.log([...set2]);
/*
[ { fname: 'Bob', sname: 'Brown' }]
*/
```

You have to compare manually both object content, and removed any duplicates.